# AWS IOT - aws-iot-device-sdk mqtt premature close

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

Have a Cordova application that is attempt to transmit some data to AWS-IOT.  I'm using the aws-iot-device-sdk for javascript https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html#iot-javascript-sdk

The data being sent is simple JSON.  The problem I having is that on Android only...some devices work and some devices don't.  On the devices that work, the data is published to the topic just fine and I can view it.  These seem to be devices running Android 4.4 but I'm not convinced that's the issue yet.

The devices that DO NOT WORK are running much much newer versions of Android.

in the error callback from mqtt I'm seeing the following:

error: Error: premature close
index.js:775 connection lost - will attempt reconnection in 2 seconds...

My question is has anyone seen/heard of this?  I've been researching for a couple days now and I'm not sure how to fix/approach this problem.

Some devices work, some don't...same code-base, same .apk

Happy to provide more detail.  Don't think code snippets are really all that relevant here but if you'd like some I can add it.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I have to guess, I hope you are using unique clientID's while connecting to mqtt. If you have duplicate mqtt clientID previous connections will be dropped immediatelly.